# android ndk + curl / localhost file download problem

Tags: curl, android-ndk

Downloading the localhost file using android ndk + lib curl. 
The error code 7 occurring, but does the Android environment occur because it is an emulator?
 How do I access localhost and receive files?
There seems to be no problem with the code.

ftp server env : windows iis
curl test env : android adk emulator x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android emulator does not see the host (Windows) computer as `localhost`. You can access the Web server by its external IP, or special [`10.0.2.2`](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) address.